# chrome and chrome canary hangs ember/rsvp promise (localstorage adapter)

Tags: google-chrome, ember.js, local-storage

Hi used this function someone mentioned on stackoverflow

```
  findOrCreate: function(type,hash){
    var self = this;
    return self.store.find(type,hash.id).then(function(friend){
      return friend;
    }, function(){
      record = self.store.recordForId(type,hash.id);
      record.loadedData();
      record.setProperties(hash);
      record.save();
      return record;
    });
  },
```

It returns promise as expected but on refreshing browser the browser becomes unresponsive.
I am using localstorage adapter

adapter : https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter

Comment: what local storage adapter, ember data doesn't include one in their library.

Comment: https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter updated question

Comment: Can you paste your implementation of the adapter?

Comment: I did not get your question. i just used the adapter out of the box(link provided in question). this is a function in controller.